# Using scss variable inside css variable

Tags: css, sass

Here is the code I am trying

```
@import "~variables";

:root
{
  --color-primary: map-get($colors, blue);
}

button {
  background: var(--color-primary);
}
```

in variables I have

```
$colors: (
        black : #000000,
        white : #FFFFFF,
        blue: : #888888
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, my buttons aren't blue. As scss is precompiled, I thought that would just work nicely.

Comment: what does your compiled code look like?

Comment: you need `--color-primary: #{map-get($colors, blue)};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape that scss function like so:

```
$colors: (
        'black' : #000000,
        'white' : #FFFFFF,
        'blue' : #888888
);

:root {
  --blue: #{map-get($colors, 'blue')}
}

body {
  color: var(--blue);
}
```

Update:
it's basically [string interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) that is needed.